# CollectionType Form Validation - "The CSRF token is invalid" and "Should not contain extra fields"

Tags: symfony

I have an array of **POSProduct** entities and I want to display a form for each of them, so the user can edit&save the one they want from a list. Previously I was iterating over the array and building a **POSProductType** form for each, and sending the array of forms to the twig template.

I've been told by multiple people that I should use a Collection instead of this technique. I wasn't able to find any examples that really cover this use case, but it was suggested I build the form directly from my controller and use the built-in CollectionType form, like so:

```
    $arrayProducts = return_array_of_product_entities();
    $form = $this->createForm('collection', $arrayProducts, array(  'type' => 'pos_product',
                                                'csrf_protection' => true,
                                                'intention' => 'vendor_add',
                                                'allow_add' => true,
                                                            ));
    return $this->render('MyBundle:Default:myform.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
```

*type => pos_product* being the POSProductType form I have defined in its own class..

The form renders fine, but when I submit and validate I get two errors:

**The CSRF token is invalid. Please try to resubmit the form / 
This form should not contain extra fields**

The CSRF token is present when I view the source of the form. I have tried every combination of the **csrf_protection** and **intention** and **allow_add** options in the createForm(), and the result is always the same.

I have also tried making my own ProductCollectionType form class so I don't have to use the default CollectionType, but I really do not understand the syntax I need. I am trying things like:

```
$builder->add('pos_product', 'collection', array(
            'type' => new POSProduct()));
```

(with every combination I can think of for the first and third arguments), and it just results in a form with a label that says "posproduct"

My solution preference would be how to create my own ProductCollectionType class that will render an array of POSProduct() entities, which are each represented by a form of type 'pos_product'

My backup solution would be to keep using the same CollectionType form I currently have, but figure out a way to make it validate.